# Проверка на пустоту блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли проверить на пустоту блока "blog", если он пустой то мы добавляем таблицу, а если в нем уже есть название и хотя бы одна ячейка, то мы к тому что есть добавляем новую запись.

Как то так я думаю?

```
if (!$('#blog')) {
  $('#blog').html(`
    <table id="n">
      <th>Название</th>
      <td>Новая занить</td>
    </table>`);
}
else
{
  $('#n').html(`  
    <td>Новая запись</td>
  `);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
if ($('#blog').html()!='') {
  $('#blog').html(
  '<table id="n"><th>Название</th><td> Новая занить</td></table>'
  );
  console.log("Условие работает");
}else{
   $('#blog').html('<table id="n"><th></th><td>Новая занить</td></table>');
   console.log("Else");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog"></div>
```

```js
if ($.trim($('#blog').html()) !== '') { 
  $('#blog').html(
  '<table id="n"><th>Название</th><td> Новая занить</td></table>'
  );
  console.log("Условие срабатывает");
}else{
  $('#n').html('<table id="n"><th>Название</th><td> Новая занить</td></table>');  
  console.log("Else");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog"></div>
```

Вариант.

```js
if ($("#blog").children().length == 0){
  $('#n').html('<table id="n"><th>Название</th><td> Новая занить</td></table>'); 
     console.log("Блок пуст от HTML");
}else{
  $('#blog').html(
  '<table id="n"><th>Название</th><td> Новая занить</td></table>'
  );
     console.log("else");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog"></div>
```

Comment: Не хватает: `$.trim($('#blog').html()) !== ''`

Comment: @Deonis а разница?

Comment: Плохо, если вы не чувствуете разницу. Пробел или перенос строки уже не будет соответствовать условию `!== ''`

Comment: Ну это и так понятно

Comment: Как я понял ему надо добавлять в таблицу новые записи, а не глобально их перезаписывать. Т.е в таблице вместо html вызывать append.

Comment: @SkyFox возможно, наверное нужно уточнить что именно и как  нужно

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ($('#blog').is(':empty')) {
  $('#blog').html(`
    <table id="n">
      <th>Название</th>
      <td>Новая занить</td>
    </table>`);
}
else
{
  $('#n').html(`  
    <td>Новая запись</td>
  `);
}
```